# How to set static IP on command line or adb shell?

Tags: adb, networking, shell, 7.1-nougat

I can't seem to use `netcfg` on Nougat. If I use `ifconfig ip` is not updating.
If there is another method to change IP on command line or `adb shell`, I am all ears.

Answer (score 5):

You can try using `ip` command.

[How it compares to ifconfig](https://p5r.uk/blog/2010/ifconfig-ip-comparison.html)

Edit: 
To set up an IP address you can use:

> ip address add 192.168.0.77 dev eth0

or the long form

> ip addr add 192.168.0.77/24 broadcast 192.168.0.255 dev eth0

look up current config using

> ip addr show

Answer (score 0):

In you terminal, run these commands:

```
adb root 
adb shell
$ ifconfig eth0 192.168.138.2  # to fix your address 
$ netcfg  # show address
```

Comment: why ifconfig IP will automaticaly lose after a while？